# How to update the password of MongoDB in java

Tags: java, mongodb

And having one difficulty as I 
 tried to update the password of existing user in mongo from code-->

```
 public static byte[] getPassword(String value) {
    try {
        return MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-512").digest(value.getBytes("UTF-8"));
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

If I wants to read the data from table the I used -->

```
public static User findByUsernameAndPassword(String username, String password) {
    return users().findOne("{username: #, shaPassword: #}", username.toLowerCase(), getSha512(password)).as(User.class);
}
```

I tried to wrote the code for update like -->

```
public Update update() {
  return users().update("{shaPassword: #}",getPassword(password)); 
}
```

but from above query if I given the input like
   {
    "username" : "admin",
    "password": "password1"
}
 From above input it is updating the password but if I chnage the name of username then it is creating the new user.
I didn;t find the proper solution for it.
please help me.

Comment: This does not look like you are using a mongo user, don't you? This is just a class named user that has a password filed (please do not store passwords in plain text). If you want to update an existing user why do you use `insert(..)` instead of `update()`?

Comment: @Robert insert() is just the temporary name I was given.
I will rename it as update

Answer (score 0):

```
// create user
db.createRole({role:'sysadmin',roles:[], privileges:[{resource:{anyResource:true},actions:['anyAction']}]})
db.createUser({user: "root",  pwd: "abcd1234",  roles: [ { role: "sysadmin", db: "admin" } ] } );
db.system.users.find();

// modify passowrd
db.updateUser("root",  {pwd: "abcde12345"} );
db.system.users.find();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But: A **good answer** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.